# How to convert SQL interval as a string to a lubridate duration?

Tags: r, lubridate

I've got a character vector like (it was a result of SQL select on an Interval type column):

```
 [1] "00:01:13"        "00:00:33"        "00:08:23"        "00:00:13"        "5 days 22:07:16" "00:01:04"        "00:00:14"        "00:05:22"       
 [9] "00:04:01"        "00:02:39"        "00:04:24"        "00:05:45"        "3 days 22:38:11" "00:05:50"        "00:03:22"        "00:00:34"       
[17] "00:03:35"        "00:02:09"        "00:01:28"        "00:06:06"        "00:03:37"        "00:00:08"
```

I need to convert it to a lubridate duration object. If days would not be there, I'd be able to do it using `hms()` function. How can I do it, when there are days in the vector?

Comment: Maybe first remove the "days" using `sub`. like `sub("^\\d+ days ", "", myVec)`.

Comment: I'm looking for a function that would let me convert all such string to a duration, and would properly include also 'days' part. If there isn't anything in lubridate or other package, I'll have to implement something by myself.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a little involved. I think the quick answer is that there is a way to do this with `lubridate`. However, you need to do some work to get the string into the proper format. The idea is to translate the information into a usable format using regex, and `stringr()`, and then to translate the data into the `period` format.

```
test <-c("00:01:13","00:00:33","00:08:23","00:00:13",
         "5 days 22:07:16", "00:01:04","00:00:14","00:05:22")
test_df <- data.frame(time = test)
```

The first thing is to reformat the data into a format that is usable:

```
test_df <- test_df %>% 
 mutate(time = stringr::str_replace_all(time, ':', ' ')) %>% 
 mutate(time = stringr::str_replace(time, '\\sdays', '')) %>% 
 mutate(time = ifelse(nchar(time) < 10, paste('0', time), time)) %>% 
 separate(time, c('day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second')) ))
```

We can then `paste()` back together, and use `hms()` and `lubridate` to get the data into a good format.

```
test_df <- test_df %>% 
 mutate(time = paste(hour, minute, second)) %>% 
 mutate(time = hms(time)) %>% 
 mutate(time = time + days(day))
```

Does this meet the need?

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend using ISO 8601 format wherever possible. If you can change your query to return data in this format, you can afterwards use `lubridate::as.period()` to convert from character to period in R.

E.g. in postgres you can do within a transaction:

```
BEGIN;

SET LOCAL intervalstyle = 'iso_8601';
SELECT (INTERVAL '6 years 5 months 4 days 3 hours 2 minutes 1 second')::text;

COMMIT;
```

Which will return a ISO 8601 string that is unambiguous and easily parseable:

```
P6Y5M4DT3H2M1S
```

```
> lubridate::as.period("P6Y5M4DT3H2M1S")
[1] "6y 5m 4d 3H 2M 1S"
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/period.html